# bash scripting, how to parse string separated with :

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have lines that look like these

```
value: "15"

value: "20"

value: "3"
```

I am getting this as input pipe after grepping

```
... | grep value:
```

What I need is a simple bash script that takes this pipe and produce me the sum
15 + 20 + 3

So my command will be:

```
... | grep value: | calculate_sum_value > /tmp/sum.txt
```

sum.txt should contain a single number which is the sum.

How can I do with bash? I have no experience with bash at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `awk`. Something like this should work

```
... | grep value: | awk '{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

And you could possibly avoid grep alltogether like this

```
.... | awk '/^value:/{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

Update:

You can add the `"` character as a field seperator with the `-F` option.

```
... | awk -F\" '/^value:/{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

Comment: I updated my question. My values are surrounded by "". Currently, I tried your solution and it gives me 0. Any ideas why this happens? Could this be because of ""?

Comment: @Bob try using the `"` character as a delimiter (read update)

Answer (score 3):

My first try was to grab the stuff on the right of the colon and let bash sum it:

```
$ sum=0
$ cat sample.txt | while IFS=: read key value; do ((sum += value)); done
bash: ((: "15": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""15"")
bash: ((: "20": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""20"")
bash: ((: "3": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""3"")
0
```

So, have to remove the quotes. Fine, use a fancy Perl regex to extract the first set of digits to the right of the colon:

```
$ cat sample.txt | grep -oP ':\D+\K\d+'
15
20
3
```

OK, onwards:

```
$ cat sample.txt | grep -oP ':\D+\K\d+' | while read n; do ((sum+=n)); done; echo $sum
0
```

Huh? Oh yeah, running `while` in a pipeline puts the modifications to sum in a subshell, not in the current shell. Well, do the echo in the subshell too:

```
$ cat sample.txt | grep -oP ':\D+\K\d+' | { while read n; do ((sum+=n)); done; echo $sum; }
38
```

That's better, but still the value is not in the current shell. Let's try something trickier

```
$ set -- $(cat sample.txt | grep -oP ':\D+\K\d+')
$ sum=$(IFS=+; bc <<< "$*")
$ echo $sum
38
```

And yes, UUOC, but it's a placeholder for whatever the OP's pipeline was.